# Multiple Invoke / BeginInvoke calls not finishing without Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the below code is run within a background worker thread:

```
while (StaticVideoList.DecodedFramesList.Count > 0)
{
    if (StaticVideoList.DecodedFramesList.ContainsKey(a))
    {
        byte[] output;

        if(StaticVideoList.DecodedFramesList.TryRemove(a, out output))
        {

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(output);

            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

            a++;

            this.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                textEdit7.Text = "Num Frame: " + a.ToString() + " / " + (1000m / ((decimal)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / (decimal)a)).ToString();
                pictureEdit1.Image = img;
            });

            // Works if I do this.. 10 is the minium. 
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

}
```

My issue is unless I add a `Thread.Sleep(10)` within the loop not all of the Invoke calls are made. The whole loop is called but only 20% of the invoke calls are made (it gets 20% in then stops, not intermittent results)

If i step through in debugging it works fine as well.

Thought maybe the issue was when the Background Worker thread finishes it cancels any Invokes made from it. But putting a Thread.Sleep(10000) to hang the background thread up longer didn't do anything.

Is there a limit to how fast you can make invoke calls?

Also `BeginInvoke` has the same "issue"

Comment: backgroundworker contains functionality for updating progrss

Comment: I have used that as an alternative with reportProgress and passing data in the userState parameter But i'm still confused on why the above doesn't work

Comment: When you say *"doesn't work"* do you mean Invoke calls are actually missed or the UI is missing updates? Are you sure the updates just aren't happening so fast that you don't notice them?

Comment: @James It stops 20% in. I can see it run through the first 110/500 images fine. Then it just stops at that position. i.e. does not run through to the rest. So definitely not running through to fast or it would end at 500/500

Comment: @furier i'm struggling to workout how you await an invoke. Do I need to use a task for that?!

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a race condition in your loop - it's like you end up with 'a' not being list but still having *something* in the list so you end up in an infinite loop. Also, you should wrap your MemoryStream with a using statement to make sure it's getting disposed correctly. You should probably do the same with your Image as well but I'm unsure if the PictureBox takes a copy of it...

Comment: @MitchWheat actually reportProgress is doing the same thing now!

Comment: Whenever you are dealing with a static list you need to use some form of synchronization - try using a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @furier to use the await keyword the container method must be declared as async - regardless, you can only await functions which return an "awaitable" object like a Task so you can't do this with Invoke/ BeginInvoke.

Comment: @James I am a ConcurrentDictionary? Basically I have a load of worker threads putting "decoded" frames into a ConcurrentDictionary with the key being the frame number. The `StaticVideoList.DecodedFramesList.ContainsKey(a)` should stop it ever looking for a frame that's not ready yet and stop any issues with synchronisation?

Comment: it is possible the try remove could fail. hmm you maybe on to something. I've put a if around the TryRemove. But still having the same issue.

Comment: @james yeah so ConcurrentDictionary will handle the synchronization of the removal, however, you aren't synchronizing the mutation of 'a' - that means 1 thread could read 'a' and then another thread changes it before it's hit the if statement or 2 threads read 'a' at the same time but one gets past the if statement first, removes it from the list and then the other thread hits the if and doesn't pass the check so ends up in an infinite loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48171/discussion-between-james-and-james)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You are fire-hosing the UI thread.  At the critical point, it is just processing the Invoke() calls and not doing anything else anymore.  Like painting the picture box and responding to input.  It doesn't make sense to *not* call Sleep(), you need to pace the display of the images at a constant rate.  With the side-benefit that you also don't fire-hose the UI thread anymore and make it go catatonic.  A significant other problem is that you don't dispose old images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke to me would appear to be a red herring. The fact that the loop appears to "stop" but works when you sleep the thread would suggest to me that you have a race condition.

My advice would be strip your loop back to the bare minimum & rebuild it until you hit the issue again - that should help you identify where the problem is.